# Total of the columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Existing Query**

```
SELECT nmindar,
         count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Allotted') Allotted,
         count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Vacant') Vacant,
         count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Amenities') Amenities
  FROM plotboundary  where indzone='Belagavi Zone' group by nmindar order by nmindar
```

[image: Expected Result]

I want to get the Total of Allotted, Vacant and Amenities.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Lookup `rollup` in the Postgres manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS

Comment: **I tried using Roll up** SELECT nmindar,
         count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Allotted') AS Allotted,
         count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Vacant') AS Vacant,
         count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Amenities') AS Amenities
  FROM plotboundary  where indzone='Belagavi Zone' group by rollup (Allotted, Vacant, Amenities ) order by nmindar. **I am getting error "Allotted" column doesn't exists.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT nmindar,
     count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Allotted') Allotted,
     count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Vacant') Vacant,
     count(indx) FILTER(WHERE indx='Amenities') Amenities
FROM plotboundary  
where indzone='Belagavi Zone' 
group by nmindar 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'ZZZZZZZZZZZ' as nmindar, 
      SUM(Allotted) as Allotted,
      SUM(Vacant) as Vacant,
      SUM(Amenities) as Amenities
FROM (the original query) sub

order by nmindar
```